# changing "listitem" reference in listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` in my `ListActivity` which is inflated with an adapter. There is a `Handler` and i call its `postDelayed()` method to run a `refresh()` recursively of the `ListView` (with the help of `notifyDataSetChanged()`). `postDealyed()` is set to 1 second.

Now, there are `ContextMenus` for all the item/rows of this `ListView`.

I want to set a row's/item's background separately from its `ContextMenu` using this code (with getting the position of the "longpressed" row/item):

```
  public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
  ...
    case R.id.highlight:
        ListView lv = (ListView)getListView();
        View row = (View) lv.getChildAt(info.position);
        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 22, 100, 100));
      return true;
  ...
```

When i run the app the selected row's background gets changed (as it should), however every second (so at every refresh of the `ListView`) another row of it changes and the selected row changes back to its original state. After another second everything changes back. If i slide over the rows of the `ListView` other rows are getting flashing aswell. Just like if the references were changing or i really don't know. If i stop sliding the flashing backgrounds have a pattern until the next slide when it gets another pattern.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your Views are getting recycled. Your "highlighting" code needs to update the backing model of the list item and set its "highlighted" property to true, it should not be changing the View directly. When you render your item (in your adapter) you check if this property is true, if it is, then use the background you specified, otherwise set it back to the default.

Comment: Hm, i thought it would solve the problem but i've edited the code as you suggested and the problem still remains. Now the adapter checks whether the row needs another background or not. If it needs the adapter overwrites the background with setBackgroundColor. If i slide the ListView the same flashy thing remains.

Comment: However if i overwrite the background not just for the row that needs to be highlighted but for all rows in the adapter (with black color for the others for example) it will work but then i loose the original onlongpress visual behavior of the rows. I know i can change them to be the same as it was but it would be better if i didn't have to set the background of the other rows.

Comment: anyway, i moved the code to the adapter and set not just the one of the convertViews but all of them with other backgrounds/selectors ect. depending on if it's needed to be highlighted or not.

Comment: Yep, once you get your logic right, then you can move on to the next step: using a selector for a background color. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373500/why-cant-i-set-my-custom-listview-items-background-dynamically/6373633#6373633).